# how can I call a PHP page from a bootstrap modal window?

Tags: javascript, php, bootstrap-4

I have a doubt that I can't solve. From a PHP page I call a typical modal window in which I always had a button that updated or added or deleted records, but now I need to place 2 buttons and that the new button allows me to call a PHP page in which I have a code that downloads data and passes it to an Excel file. I don't know how to make the call to that page from the button in the modal window.

```
<div class="mb-3 row">
  <div class="col-md-6 text-center">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">update</button>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 text-center">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">download detail</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

I would appreciate any help. Thanks

Comment: Create link or use AJAX.

Comment: Hi. Markus Zeller, Could you give me an example of ajax sending a parameter to test. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In Bootstrap, you can use same button classes for `<a>` tag as well:

> The .btn classes are designed to be used with the `<button>` element.
> However, you can also use these classes on `<a>` or `<input>` elements
> (though some browsers may apply a slightly different rendering).

So your button should be done like this:

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-success">download detail</a>
```

Comment: Your solution worked my friend. I didn't know I could put this tag on a button. I was overcomplicating myself. Thank you very much.